# How to format date from mysql to jtextfield

Tags: java, mysql, parsing, format

I want to take the date as '07-07-2017' from mysql db to jtextfield.

Error:

> Cannot Format Given Object As A Date.

What can I do?

Below is my code.

```
 public void fisGetir(int fisNo) throws NumberFormatException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException{

        String tarih ;
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date simdikiZaman = df.parse(ariza.getTarih());
        tarih = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(simdikiZaman); 


        ariza = db.arizaBilgiGetir(fisNo);
        fisNoTextField.setText(String.valueOf(fisNo));
        tarihTextField.setText(ariza.getTarih());
        personelTextField.setText(ariza.getPersonel());
        islemTarihiTextField.setText(ariza.getIslemTarih());
        islemSaatTextField.setText(ariza.getIslemSaat());
    }

     public ArizaBakimListeTableSatirModel arizaBilgiGetir(int fisNo) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException
        {
             if(con == null) con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
                con.setAutoCommit(true);       

             Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
             String yol ="SELECT fisno, tarih, personel, id, islemTarih, islemSaat FROM ariza WHERE fisno= '" + fisNo +"' " ;
             System.out.println(yol);
             ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(yol);
             ArizaBakimListeTableSatirModel ariza = new ArizaBakimListeTableSatirModel();

             while (rs.next()) {
                 ariza.setFisNo(rs.getInt("fisno"));
                 ariza.setTarih(rs.getString("tarih"));
                 ariza.setPersonel(rs.getString("personel"));
                 ariza.setIslemTarihi(rs.getString("islemTarih"));
                 ariza.setIslemSaat(rs.getString("islemSaat"));
                 ariza.setId(rs.getInt("id"));
                 ariza.setKayitDurum(true);  //kayıt durumu var mı kontrol
             }
             return ariza;
        }
```

Comment: So, you're pulling a `String` value from the database; `ariza.setTarih(rs.getString("tarih"));`; and then trying to pass that value to a `DateFormatter` which is going to expect a `Date` value of some kind ... and you wonder why it's not working.  Instead, store all date/time values in the database using an appropriate column type, then use the JDBC driver to store/retrieve those values using appropriate objects, like `rs.getDate("tarih")` for example

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
public void fisGetir(int fisNo) throws NumberFormatException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, ParseException{
        ariza = db.arizaBilgiGetir(fisNo);

        String tarih, islemTarih ;
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date simdikiZaman = df.parse(ariza.getTarih());
        tarih = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(simdikiZaman); 

        Date simdikiZaman2 = df.parse(ariza.getIslemTarih());
        islemTarih = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(simdikiZaman2); 

        fisNoTextField.setText(String.valueOf(fisNo));
        tarihTextField.setText(tarih);
        personelTextField.setText(ariza.getPersonel());
        islemTarihiTextField.setText(islemTarih);
        islemSaatTextField.setText(ariza.getIslemSaat());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You have using `ariza.getTarih()` before you set value to `ariza` at `ariza = db.arizaBilgiGetir(fisNo);` so that the value of object you try to parse is can be null or what value you have init in constructor, that's make the error 'can not parse'

```
Date simdikiZaman = df.parse(ariza.getTarih());
tarih = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(simdikiZaman);       
ariza = db.arizaBilgiGetir(fisNo);
```

Please change the line `ariza = db.arizaBilgiGetir(fisNo);` to ahead before using `ariza`

```
ariza = db.arizaBilgiGetir(fisNo);
Date simdikiZaman = df.parse(ariza.getTarih());
tarih = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").format(simdikiZaman);
```

Comment: @Mr.Guler If an answer is solving your problem then you should accept this answer instead of write again the code as solution. This make others don't know that this question is answered or not